# Waiting for a new deployment to fully initialize before swap the staging/production slot (swap VIP)?

Tags: powershell, azure

I use the following code to swap my newly deployed application from the staging slot into the production slot (swap VIP):

```
Get-HostedService -serviceName $serviceName -subscriptionId $subcription -certificate $certificate | Get-Deployment -slot staging | Move-Deployment |Get-OperationStatus –WaitToComplete
```

I thought that the -WaitToComplete flag would make sure all VMs have fully initialize before doing the swap however it doesn't and it performs the swap at which time the newly deployed application in the production slot is still initializing and is unavailable for about 5/10min while it initializes fully.

What is the best way to make sure that the application is fully initialized before doing the Swap VIP operation?

Comment: I need this as I'm using an automated build to deploy to Azure

Answer (score 9):

This PowerShell snippet will wait until every instance is ready (building on the answer @astaykov gave).

It queries the state of the running instances in the staging slot, and only if all are showing as 'ready' will it leave the loop.

```
$hostedService = "YOUR_SERVICE_NAME"

do {
    # query the status of the running instances
    $list = (Get-AzureRole -ServiceName $hostedService `
                           -Slot Staging `
                           -InstanceDetails).InstanceStatus 

    # total number of instances
    $total = $list.Length

    # count the number of ready instances
    $ready = ($list | Where-Object { $_ -eq "ReadyRole" }).Length

    Write-Host "$ready out of $total are ready"

    $notReady = ($ready -ne $total)
    If ($notReady) {
        Start-Sleep -s 10
    }
}
while ($notReady)
```

Comment: Nice one, it would be nice to add some sort of timeout though (e.g. 5-10 minutes), because if one of the roles fails to start you will be stuck in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that what you might actually be seeing is the delay that it takes for the DNS entries to be propagated and become available.

What you should find is that once the status is reported as **Ready** you may not be able to access your site using the staging URL "http://.cloudapp.net" you will find that it might not come up... but if you look on the Management Portal you will see at the bottom of the Properties a value for 'VIP' - if you use that IP address "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx you should be able to get to your site.

When you do a SWAP you will find similar behavior. It will take some time for the DNS updates to propagate, but you will likely see that you can still access the site with either the IP address or the staging address (if it has become available).

Finally, 1 question... based on your question it sounds like you might be deploying to staging as part of your build then immediately promoting to a production deployment... is this correct, and if so why not just deploy to the production deployment? (I'm not suggesting that deploying directly into production is a best practice... but if that is your workflow I see no benefit to the temporary deployment to staging)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. To answer your question: The PowerShell script is part of an entire automated and semi-autoamted build process that sometimes automatically deploys straight to an environment if its for CI or Test but for more secured environments like Production and Staging it has an additional manual step where testers verify the new deployment sitting in the staging slot. That is why we don't deploy straight to the production slot.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is it then after the testers verify the deployment in the Staging deployment that you are seeing the issue?  If so then I would expect the 'delay in availability' you are seeing is very likely caused the the DNS change being propagated. Again you could try to test this by accessing your site using the VIP directly and see if it responds as expected.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yes I've tracked it down to a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with PowerShell, but from my experience with shells at all you are pipelining commands. Each set before a pipe charachter (|) represents a single command which would pass its result to the next command in the pipe (command after the pipe character). And because you are executing these commands before the depolyment is fully complete, that's why you get the newly deployed app swapped to the production slot.

First thing to note here is that you have "-WaitToComplete" argument just for the last command, which is actually Get-OperationStatus.

Other thing that I see is that this powershell commands will just do the vip swap. What about deployment?

From what you descriped it appears that your build server is auto deploying to staging, and you have post-build event that executes the swap script. What Mike Erickson suggests here would make sense, if your flow is like that - immediately swap after depoloy to staging. Why would you deploy to staging, if you are going to make a swap without checking application health first? However I would not recommend direct depolyment to the server (delete + deploy), but a service upgrade. Because when we do service upgrade, our deployment keeps its public IP address. If we delete + deploy we get a new public IP address. And the public IP address for a hosted service is already guaranteed to not be changed untill deployment is deleted.

Finally, you shall expand your PowerShell script a bit. First include a routine which will check (and wait untill) the staging slot to be "ready", and then perform the swap. As I said, I'm not much into powershell, but I'm sure this is feasible.

Just my 2 cents.

**UPDATE**

After revisiting [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg271300), I now understand something. You are waiting for operation to complete, but this is the VIP-SWAP operation which you are waiting to complete. If your stating deployment is not yet ready, you have to wait for it to become ready. And also like Mike mentioned, there might be DNS delay, which is noted at the end of the [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg271300):

> **Note:**
>
> If you visit the production site shortly after its promotion, the DNS
>   name might not be ready. If you encounter a DNS error (404), wait a
>   few minutes and try again. Keep in mind that Windows Azure creates DNS
>   name entries dynamically and that the changes might take few minutes
>   to propagate.

**UPDATE 2**

Well, you will have to query for all the roles and all of their instances and wait for all of them to be ready. Technical you could conduct the VIP swap with at least one instance per role being ready, but I think that would complicate the script even more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minor tweak to Richard Astbury's example above that will retry a limited number of times. All credit to him for original sample code, so I'd vote for him as the answer most to the point. Simply posting this variation here as an alternative for people to copy/paste as needed:

```
$hostedService = "YOUR_SERVICE_NAME"
# Wait roughly 10 minutes, plus time required for Azure methods
$remainingTries = 6 * 10

do {
    $ready=0
    $total=0
    $remainingTries--

    # query the status of the running instances
    $list = (Get-AzureRole -ServiceName $hostedService -Slot Staging -InstanceDetails).InstanceStatus 

    # count the number of ready instances
    $list | foreach-object { IF ($_ -eq "ReadyRole") { $ready++ } }

    # count the number in total
    $list | foreach-object { $total++ } 

    "$ready out of $total are ready"

    if (($ready -ne $total) -and ($remainingTries -gt 0)) {
        # Not all ready, so sleep for 10 seconds before trying again
        Start-Sleep -s 10
    }
    else {
        if ($ready -ne $total) {
            throw "Timed out while waiting for service to be ready: $hostedService"
        }

        break;
    }
}
while ($true)
```